# Enable Magisk Hide on Magisk 20.4

Tags: magisk

[Magisk 20.4 release notes](https://github.com/topjohnwu/magisk_files/blob/598fee44ab7528205b7088716d1197dd8e38532d/notes.md) say

> Please be aware that MagiskHide is no longer enabled by **default**

(Emphasis supplied)

*Default* probably means there is a workaround to enable it but I couldn't find a way to do it or find anything on searching

Edit:Enabling Magisk Hide in Menu does not reveal the settings option to select apps for applying hide

How do I do that ? (Please don't suggest installing earlier versions, which I may well do, if I don't find a way )

Comment: Does the "Magisk Hide" option remain active once enabled?

Comment: Yes it does @Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the option to enable "Magisk Hide" in the settings of Magisk app:

[image]

Afterwards the side menu has a new entry:

[image]

Comment: @beeshyams If I enable Magisk Hide the settings side menu gets a new entry.